# MySQL multiple table join Update and Delete where joined data unknown

Tags: mysql

Background: I have been charged with running a job to delete data stored before one time frame and hash data stored before another time frame. The data set is huge and I cannot rely on linked data being present in all joined tables and one table can be joined on 2 fields.

```
t1 = {id,   t2_id,  t2_2_id,    bool_one,  bool_two, bool_three , a_date}
t2 = {id,   2_id,   other_field}
t3 = {id,   t1_id,  other_field}
```

First I need to delete all records where a_date is 6 months or older and  bool_one = 1 and (bool_two = 1 or bool_three = 1) Or (bool_one = 0 and a_date is older then 1 month)

Next I need to update all records hashing data that a_date is 3 months or older and  bool_one = 1 and (bool_two = 1 or bool_three = 1) Or (bool_one = 0 and a_date is older then 1 month)

I would like to know considering the query below, what happens if one or more joined tables have no linked data? and if there is anyway to still delete / update the data from joined that is linked and ignore any that is not.

So for example delete all from t1 and t2 but no linked data in t3 so ignore or delete all from t1 and t3 but no linked data in t3 so ignore or only data in t1 so ignore t2 and t3 and so on...

Code:

```
DELETE a, b, c, d
        FROM t1 a
             INNER JOIN t2 b on b.id = a.t2_id
             INNER JOIN t2 c on c.id = a.t2_2_id
             INNER JOIN t3 d on d.t1_id = a.id
        WHERE a.bool_one = 1 AND (a.bool_two = 1 OR a.bool_three = 1) 
                AND a.a_date <= Now() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
                OR (a.bool_1 = 0 AND a.a_date <= Now() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

The update query is pretty much the same so I wont include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you are doing this all through **INNER JOIN**, then you should expect the linking of records to occur end-to-end through tables `t1`, `t2` and `t3` for rows to be deleted - it's all or nothing, the same as for a SELECT.

I've put together a simplified INNER JOIN example in a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0f347/1). It has the same basic schema to mock your JOINs but I've made the WHERE clause just use a.`id` since it doesn't really matter for the demo how the records are selected, just that some are.

The mocked up data is intended to make the behaviour easy to see. In the example, `t1` has records with values 1, 2 and 3, table `t2` has records with values 1 and 2 and table `t3` has a single row with values set to 1.

If we use the a.`id` = 3 in the WHERE clause then no rows are deleted since there are no matches to link to this value through `t2` and `t3`.

Similarly, using a.`id` = 2 doesn't delete any rows because there is still no link that makes it all the way through to `t3`.

a.`id` = 1 is the only value where a link can be made through all tables and deletes the single matching records in all three tables.

If you use **LEFT JOIN** instead of INNER JOIN then you will get slightly more *forgiving* behaviour which allows for the deletion of records in the scenarios you mention e.g.

- delete all from t1 and t2 but no linked data in t3, so ignore
- delete all from t1 and t3 but no linked data in t2 (not t3), so
  ignore
- or only data in t1 so ignore t2 and t3

LEFT JOIN [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/687220) tests